# Regex - IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis

I'm working on a web application that work on modules and submodules, and URLs are like this:

```
http://website.com/DefaultHome.aspx?ctl=Module/Submodule&first=1&second=2
```

My purpose is to clean the URL, making something like

```
http://website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2
```

that IIS can process into

```
http://website.com/DefaultHome.aspx?ctl={R:0}&{R:1}
```

but my knowledge about regular expressions is too basic.

Can anyone help me making a Regex that is able to return last two url blocks into two groups?

[**EDIT**]

I apologize if the post is unclear , I'll try to clarify:
I would use an adress pattern like `website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2` but I need to process this type of url to return this: `website.com/DefaultHome.aspx?ctl=Module/Submodule&first=1&second=2`, so i need a regex that extract `Module/Submodule` and `first=1&second=2` from the first URL, for the purpose of insert the two strings in a IIS rewrite URL like this: `DefaultHome.aspx?ctl={R:0}&{R:1}`

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: I need a regex that return 2 matches, one that is `Module/Submodule`, and the second that contains other querystring parameters

Comment: I think you're over complicating your question - are *URL* 1 and 2 really necessary? If you wan't to separate the first and rest of the parameters try `ctl=([^&]*)(?:&(.*))*` (if the first always is named **ctl** - `\?[^=]*=([^&]*)(?:&(.*))*` if not). See [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/vA4jV0/1).

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Sad to say it, but it didn't help at all. You basically rewrote the same thing, just with worse formatting... :S `http://website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2` - that's not even a valid URL is it? Why is this info here? And where does `ctl={R:0}&{R:1}` come from? I guess this is some internal IIS stuff - but is it necessary info to answer your question?

Comment: `website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2` is the urls I want to use, and `website.com/DefaultHome.aspx?ctl=Module/Submodule&first=1&second=2` is the url I have now, and the url that I have to use, on my server. IIS give you the possibility to use a regex and manage the return(s) value to rewrite the url (the `{R:x}` are the matches). so i want to write in the browser `website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2`, IIS catch it, use the regex, and split the address, then compose the real url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed iis url rewrite module to test rules and here its what I came to:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="ModuleRedirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="DefaultHome.aspx?ctl={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

This will mach urls like: website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2

Comment: HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The expression "^{R:1}/(.*)$" contains a repeat expression (one of '*', '?', '+', '{' in most contexts) that is not preceded by an expression.

Comment: @Nodiink Yes, I forgot to escape curly braces.

Comment: IIS says: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.
Testing pattern in IIS Manager it says that the regex doesn't match with the url I describe in my question.

Comment: Btw, I add `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />` to avoid an error with the **&** character in the URL

Comment: Y, or you can escape it with &amp; Can I use question mark in your desired url like this: website.com/Module/Submodule?first=1&second=2. That would simplify things ;) Or maybe they need to be like that: website.com/Module/Submodule/first=1&second=2

Comment: It is just an idea to use slashes everywhere, `website.com/Module/Submodule?first=1&second=2` will be very fine anyway.

Comment: @Nodiink see then my updated answer. I will try tomorrow to make a rule with slashes instead of question mark ;)

Comment: IIS says again 404. There is anything else to write in the web.confg that maybe I didn't have considered?

Comment: @Nodiink see my updated answer. I've installed url rewrite to test it and it works now.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your time and patience :D